# Storyboard is not showing custom color hex code in XCode 12.0.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

After updating to the latest Xcode, into storyboard I am not able to see actual custom color hex code. It is showing a white(FFFFFF) color hex code all time.
Can someone please help me with this? Please check the below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: do you have the latest Xcode version? Maybe a restart will help.

Comment: Already did but no luck.

Comment: I see this in Xcode 12 too. I would recommend filing a bug report with Apple. It's easy to do with the Feedback application.

Comment: @matt Yes sure. Thank you.

Answer (score 32):

I have noticed this same problem since the latest XCode Version 12.0.1.

A workaround that works for me is to

1. Click on the custom color to bring up the color chooser.
2. The color chooser is the wrong color, but tap on any other color in the color chooser.
3. Tap Cmd+Z to undo the color change.  Magically the original custom color is now selected in the color chooser.

Comment: Nice workaround! I've found a couple of variants on it but they are all basically the same idea: change the color and then reverse that.

Comment: Thank you!  Yeah, occasionally little twerks crop up in xCode that have little work arounds!  Thanks for your advice on the related post too!

Answer (score 4):

Almost the same idea work around and quicker without needing to change the color (and then reverse):

- Select your color (this will make the color picker appear) in the drop list.
- Select again your color (with the picker still shown) in the drop list (not in the color picker window), it will update the picker to your color.

Comment: I think the idea about reversing is that you often don't know the RGB values are and you click to see the values, and see the values for white instead? Without knowing the values, how do you select your color?

Comment: You select again the color in the picker as list, not as "RGB setting" additional window..

Comment: Ah, ok, select it in the list, without closing the picker window, cool, that works too!

Comment: @auspicious99 I've updated the answer to reflect that detail to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has now fixed this issue in Xcode 12.5

> Fixed an issue where the custom colors swatch in an inspector’s color
> properties displayed an incorrectly offset focus indicator.

Reference: [Apple Xcode 12.5 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-12_5-release-notes)

[image]

Comment: Actually I think it has been fixed in Xcode 12.4, not just Xcode 12.5? At least in my Xcode 12.4 the problem seems to have been fixed.

Comment: @auspicious99 Wow that's good. You are ahead of apple. :D

Comment: Haha, maybe they missed it and put it only in 12.5 release notes. Or maybe my Xcode 12.4 is special :-). Anyway, let's not lose any sleep over it.