# Get custom color RGB code from Xcode Inspector

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel

I have a label with custom color in storyboard. How do we find the RGB color code for the color?

[image]

double clicking on the custom color showed the colors window but did not display the color codes for the color, instead it displayed the default values.

Duplicate of [Storyboard is not showing custom color hex code in XCode 12.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64534173/storyboard-is-not-showing-custom-color-hex-code-in-xcode-12-0-1)

Comment: Yes, it's a known bug.

Answer (score 3):

When you click on the custom color, it should open the Colors Window.

On the Colors Window, click on the second tab on top, nameed `Color Sliders`.

On the drop down menu, click on the GreyScale Slider, and choose, `RGB Sliders`. That should show you the RGB details.

If that still doesn't work, maybe check your Assets, if you have a color named Custom there.