# Get current color information of. my custom view in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xib

I want to know the color info(hex or RGB) of view in the .xib file with Xcode.

In the past, I used to get color info by clicking 'custom' in the background section of my view.

[image]

[image: Current color info was displayed]

But, after updating Xcode several times, the popup window shows trash value irrelevant to the current color.

What I want to do is creating a new view that has the same background color as another view that I created a few days ago. Unfortunately, I forgot the color information but there is no way to get a color value.

The color picker in Xcode returns color information, but the value is not correct because it returns a different value every time.

Comment: Right click on the Xib (from the File Inspector), Open as Source code, find your element, you should be able to find the hexa color.

Comment: Can you share the different values it returns each time you try to get the color of it?

Comment: Yes, it’s a known bug. But there are decent workarounds.

Comment: @Larme Wow..It's one of gorgeous way. Thank you.

Comment: @matt Wow.. I solved this issue in this way.(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64534173/storyboard-is-not-showing-custom-color-hex-code-in-xcode-12-0-1) I really thanks to you :D

Comment: @Son I posted an answer there also, with maybe what I think is a quicker work around.